# os.path.exists returns False, but os.path.abspath returns the path

Tags: python, file-not-found, os.path

This code should extract pictures from a xlsx file and save a copy and rename it three times in a new directory.
os.mkdir creates the directory on the desktop and saves the first picture but after that I get

```
    os.rename(filename, new_name)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Impossible  to find the specified file: 'image1.jpeg' -> 'newPicone0.jpeg
```

When I check the absolute path of the directory I got this
`os.path.abspath('renamedPix')`
`'C:\\Users\\divel\\Desktop\\XLSpix\\renamedPix'`
even though the directory is not in the XLSpix folder but on the desktop.

Checking for the  directory's existence I get this:
`os.path.exists('renamedPix')`
`False`

I don't understand what is causing the problem.
Here is the complete code:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import re
import os
import shutil

file_name= "fote.xlsx"
directory= "renamedPix"
parent_dir = "C:\\Users\\divel\\Desktop"
path = os.path.join(parent_dir, directory)
os.mkdir(path)

with ZipFile(file_name, 'r') as zipObj:
     counter = 0
     
     for file in zipObj.infolist():
         name = file.filename
         match = re.findall("jpeg$", name)
         
         if match:
            filename = os.path.basename(file.filename)
            
            for i in range(3):
                source = zipObj.open(file)
                target = open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'wb')
                
                with source, target :
                    shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)
                pic_names = ['one', 'two', 'three']
                new_name = 'newPic'+pic_names[i]+str(counter)+'.jpeg'
                os.rename(filename, new_name)
            counter += 1
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why are you using `ZipFile` to open a .xlsx file?

Comment: @astrochun all office files ending with "x" (docx, pptx, xlsx, etc) are actually zip files

Comment: Ah. Given that you're trying to extract the images from a specific file, we really need a minimal reproducible XLSX to test out your code.

Comment: What do you get from `os.path.exists('C:\\Users\\divel\\Desktop\\XLSpix\\renamedPix')`?

Comment: @YashvanderBarnel   I get False.

Comment: If I don't use os.mkdir to create a new directory and save the pictures directly to ```'C:\\Users\\divel\\Desktop\\XLSpix```  the code works just fine.

Comment: `os.path.abspath` doesn't do any searching or even check if the file exists; it just follows some basic rules set forward by the OS. Right now on my system I can do `os.path.abspath("hjewgrhiewyfugwye")` in any folder and get a valid path. That doesn't mean that file exists anywhere on my machine.

Comment: @Silvio Mayolo  That's valuable information, thank you. Anyway I can see the folder on the desktop but os.path.exits returns False. That I really can't understand.

Comment: It seems that `filename` and `newname` are both relative names? That means, they are assume to be in the current working directory, not in the directory `path` points to. Should you `join()` them with `path` before you pass them to `os.rename()`? I guess you want `os.rename(target, os.path.join(path, newname)`?

Comment: I tried it and got this error ```File "C:/Users/divel/Desktop/XLSpix/update2.py", line 30, in <module>
    os.rename(target, os.path.join(path, new_name))
TypeError: rename: src should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not BufferedWrite```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It should read `os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, newname))`. The idea is that you specify both arguments to `rename()` with their full path.

Comment: @DanielJunglas It works like a charm! This was a very good lesson to learn. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Turning my comment into an answer: The problem was that the arguments to `os.rename()` were only file names, not path names. Thus the OS attempted to rename the files in the current working directory (where they did not exist). Passing the full path names to rename fixes the issue:

```
os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, newname))
```

Comment: You made things even clearer now. Once again, thank you.